# customize voice recognition android

Tags: android, customization, voice-recognition

I am using the voice recognition feature in my android app and I would like to add custom components such as "Speak after the beep" or add custom messages when there is a connection error for instance. How can I do? 
For instance, when there is no internet connection, I get this message "Connection problem" but i cannot find this string in the code. Where is it?

Thanks a lot!